MOXA Web UI issue with VPN MTU lengths?
When I access the MOXA switch (IKS-G6824A-20GSFP) web UI locally (within the subnet) and navigate to the VRRP configuration page, it works perfectly:
Web UI Screenshot
However, when I use an OpenVPN connection (setup by me, so I can mess with as many parameters as needed), and then navigate across the VPN to the same web page (VRRP config), I get a very strange issue. Some of the web page elements appear missing:
Web UI Screenshot - Broken
I narrowed it down to what appears to be an MTU size issue. When connecting locally, the negotiated MSS (maximum segment size) is 1460, as you'd expect. 1460+20(TCP Header)+20(IPv4 Header)+14(Ethernet framing) = 1514 as shown in wireshark:
Screenshot of the expected packet capture
When accessing the page via an OpenVPN connection (to a 4G Teltonika router located on site, with a publicly routable IPv4 address), there is an obvious indicator of an error. 1). the truncation here detected by Wireshark, 2). an error in Firefox in the network activity log - "NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER", and 3). if I copy out the HTML bytes and compare them side-by-side, it is just straight-up truncated. It is NOT truncated at every TCP fragment - only the final TCP segement appears truncated, meaning that the browser is receiving "valid" HTML up until the point at which it truncates.
Screenshot of the packet capture with an error
HTML packet truncation, looking at the "reassembled" packet in Wireshark
BTW in that last screenshot, you'd expect to see </body> and </html> at the end, which is confirmed in the correct response (locally):
Correct HTML packet - the end of the reassembled packet
When accessing the page via an OpenVPN connection (to a 4G Teltonika router located on site, with a publicly routable IPv4 address), the MTU is slightly lower as you'd expect to allow for the VPN overheads. The VPN itself uses UDP, with the TCP connection shown in the screenshot below captured from the "OpenVPN Connection" Network Adapter. The MSS I think is intercepted by OpenVPN and lowered a bit to optimize potential "double fragmenting" (fragmenting the TCP connection AND fragmenting the underlying UDP connection?).
As shown in the screenshot above, it appears that the MSS drops to 1361 (instead of 1460). I believe this is with the default setting (i.e. no mssfix parameter in the OpenVPN config file). I suspect this defaults to 1425, because when I add in the line "mssfix 1400" to the config file, the TCP MSS in Wireshark drops by 25, from 1361 to 1336.
Interestingly, when I add the line "mssfix 1400" to the VPN config file, more of the VRRP web page is missing!!!!, implying (and confirmed by copying out the HTML bytes and comparing side-by-side) that slightly more of the HTML is truncated.
Web UI with even more missing using mssfix 1400
What in the actual heck is going on here? Is this OpenVPN playing silly buggers or is this a MOXA Web UI TCP fragmentation bug???
Edit 1:
I tried setting the MTU on the machine local to the switch down such that both TCP dumps generated the same size packets (1415 size ethernet frames in wireshark). I used the command netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "<INTERFACE NAME>" mtu=1401 store=persistent:
Local Machine with Reduced MTU vs Remote Machine with same MTU
So I suppose this points the finger more at the VPN?

mssfix doesn't re-segment the TCP traffic; it only edits the MSS field during the handshake, after which the endpoints are responsible for sending segments of the right size.
I would usually bet on the embedded firmware's TCP and/or webserver getting things wrong. Forgetting to send the last incomplete buffer at the end of a loop is not that uncommon a mistake (generally speaking).
But if possible, test this without a VPN, directly connecting to the same switch and requesting a lower MSS – you can also have iptables/nftables apply a similar "mssfix", or lower your Ethernet interface's MTU and have TCP adapt, or (if using a Linux client) specify the desired TCP MSS as part of a routing table entry.

Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the following (Windows 10): netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "<INTERFACE NAME>" mtu=1401 store=persistent on the machine that is local to the switch. The web UI worked fine! So, something in the VPN must be triggering the issue.
1401 was chosen, such that in wireshark, both my remote machine and the local machine were sending ethernet frames of size 1415.

Did it result in the lower MSS being negotiated? I'm not very familiar with the Windows side of this configuration.
